Symfony 6.4 - Impersonating User - Cannot access routes with parameters
context: I'm developing a Symfony 6.4 application where a parent can have several children and interact with the application under their names. So I have a parent (User entity) linked to one or more child(ren) (User entity).
I decided to use the “impersonate user” feature included in Symfony:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
As parents don't need to register an email address for their child when they sign up, I had to use the ID and not the username to change the user. I did this with a custom Controller, a custom Voter and configure a second security provider.
User switching works well: I can switch from Parent to Child, back to Parent and so on.
However, when I use a Child and try to navigate to a route with a parameter (ID for example), it doesn't work and I get this error message:
An exception has been raised when rendering a template (“Some mandatory parameters are missing (”id“ ) to generate a URL for route ‘app_message_detail’.”).
When I inspect the generated HTML code, the ID is indeed present.
When I dump into my controller, the ID is present.
When I check in the debug toolbar, I see that there is a 302 response.
I've checked that the parameter has been passed to the controller: ok
I've checked that the user has the right roles: ok
I've checked that the route works with a Parent : ok
Files:
config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # Used to switch user feature
        app_switch_user:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: id
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                enable_csrf: true

            login_throttling:
                max_attempts: 3

            logout:
                path: app_logout

            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker

            switch_user:
                {
                    role: ROLE_PARENT,
                    parameter: _switch_user,
                    provider: app_switch_user,
                }

src/controller/UserController.php
#[Route('/switch-user/{userId}', name: 'app_switch_user')]
#[IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
public function switchUser($userId, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker): RedirectResponse
{
    $user = $this->userRepository->find($userId);

    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException($this->translator->trans('error.user_not_found'));
    }

    if (!$authChecker->isGranted('SWITCH', $user)) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException($this->translator->trans('error.access_denied'));
    }

    $this->addFlash('warning', $this->translator->trans('warning.user_switched', ['firstname' => $user->getFirstname(), 'lastname' => $user->getLastname()]));

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home', [
        '_switch_user' => $user->getId(),
    ]);
}

src/Security/Voter/SwitchUserVoter.php
namespace App\Security\Voter;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;

class SwitchUserVoter extends Voter
{
    protected function supports(string $attribute, mixed $subject): bool
    {
        return $attribute === 'SWITCH' && $subject instanceof User;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, mixed $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->canSwitch($user, $subject);
    }

    private function canSwitch(User $parent, User $enfant)
    {
        return in_array($enfant, $parent->getChildren()->toArray());
    }
}

src/controller/MessageController.php
#[Route('/{messageId}', name: 'app_message_detail')]
#[IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
public function detail($messageId): Response
{
    try {
        $message = $this->findMessage($messageId);

        // Mark message as read
        $messageStatus = $this->messageStatusRepository->findOneBy(['message' => $message, 'receiver' => $this->getUser()]);

        if ($messageStatus) {
            $messageStatus->setStatus(true);

            $this->entityManager->persist($messageStatus);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('message/detail.html.twig', [
            "message" => $message
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->addFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_messages');
    }
}


It seems your error is in templates. Maybe you are calling "path()" function and missing some parameters. Can you share your page code? I mean the TWIG file in which you have error

I don't think so because my route and links work well if I use the parent. I find another solution, I will post it :)

I finally find an other solution : I rewrite the switch-user and exit-switch-user method.
I based myself on this article : impersonating-users-in-symfony-methods-and-best-practices
src/Controller/SwitchUserController.php
#[Route('/switch-user/{userId}', name: 'app_switch_user')]
#[IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
public function impersonate($userId, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker, Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $parent = $this->getUser();
    $this->ensureUserExists($parent);

    $child = $this->userRepository->find($userId);
    $this->ensureUserExists($child);

    $this->ensureAccessGranted($authChecker, $child);

    $this->switchUser($request, $child);

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
}

private function ensureUserExists($user): void
{
    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException($this->translator->trans('error.user_not_found'));
    }
}

private function ensureAccessGranted(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker, $child): void
{
    if (!$authChecker->isGranted('SWITCH', $child)) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException($this->translator->trans('error.access_denied'));
    }
}

private function switchUser(Request $request, $child): void
{
    $tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');
    $originalToken = $tokenStorage->getToken();

    if (!$request->getSession()->get('_switch_user')) {
        $request->getSession()->set('_switch_user', serialize($originalToken));
    }

    $impersonationToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(
        $child,
        "main",
        $child->getRoles()
    );

    $tokenStorage->setToken($impersonationToken);

    $this->addFlash('warning', $this->translator->trans('warning.user_switched', [
        'firstname' => $child->getFirstname(),
        'lastname' => $child->getLastname()
    ]));
}

#[Route('/exit-switch-user', name: 'app_exit_switch_user')]
public function unimpersonate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');

    if ($request->getSession()->get('_switch_user')) {
        $originalToken = unserialize($request->getSession()->get('_switch_user'));

        $request->getSession()->remove('_switch_user');
        $tokenStorage->setToken($originalToken);

        $user = $originalToken->getUser();

        $this->addFlash('warning', $this->translator->trans('warning.user_switched', [
            'firstname' => $user->getFirstname(),
            'lastname' => $user->getLastname()
        ]));
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
}

src/Secuity/Voter/SwitchUserVoter.php
class SwitchUserVoter extends Voter
{
    protected function supports(string $attribute, mixed $subject): bool
    {
        return $attribute === 'SWITCH' && $subject instanceof User;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, mixed $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        $parent = $token->getUser();

        if (!$parent instanceof User) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->canSwitch($parent, $subject);
    }

    private function canSwitch(User $parent, User $child): bool
    {
        if (!in_array('ROLE_PARENT', $parent->getRoles())) {
            return false;
        }

        $children = $parent->getChildren()->toArray();

        foreach ($children as $c) {
            if ($c->getId() === $child->getId()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

And finally, to get the original user :
src/Service/AccountManager.php
public function getOriginalUser()
{
    $originalToken = unserialize($this->requestStack->getSession()->get('_switch_user'));

    if ($originalToken) {
        return $originalToken->getUser();
    }

    return $this->security->getUser();
}

